# Cut Off Frequency in the Frequency Response of RC circuit

Tags: high-frequency, frequency-response, cutoff-frequency

In the frequency response curve of RC circuit, why does the curve falls rapidly after the breakpoint? It approximates to a certain amplitude upto the breakpoint. In the diagram, given below, it is approximating the gain to 0 dB. My question is, why does it suddenly falls after the breakpoint?

[image]

Comment: Please post a circuit diagram. Are you familiar with the derivation of its transfer function? "*It approximates to a certain amplitude...*". Can you clarify this sentence? What does it approximate?

Comment: @AJN , It approximates the gain to a certain amplitude. In the diagram, given in the question, it is approximating the gain to 0 dB. My question is, why does it suddenly falls after the breakpoint?

Comment: The figure shows the equation \$v_o = v_i \frac{1}{\sqrt{\color{red}{1+}\omega^2\dots}}\$. Does the book show its derivation? The shape of the curve is simply the plots of this equation. The drops becomes significant because that is where \$\omega^2 R^2 C^2\$ crosses 1.

Comment: Also, IMO, it is not sudden. The suddenness is only an illusion created by the log scale with which the frequency axis is plotted. Plot the same thing in linear scale and you can see that every thing is smooth and not sudden.

Comment: If you change the y axis from 3 dB /div to 20dB/div would you see it differently?

Comment: @AJN Got your point, thank you so much for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why does it suddenly fall after the cut-off frequency

Beyond the cutoff frequency \$\omega^2R^2C^2\$ is greater than 1 and then \$1 + \omega^2R^2C^2\$ looks more and more like \$\omega^2R^2C^2\$.

Therefore, for \$\omega > \frac{1}{RC}\$,

$$
\frac{ |V_{out}| }{|V_{in}|} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \omega^2R^2C^2}} 
\approx
     \frac{1}{\sqrt{\omega^2R^2C^2}} 
   = \frac{1}{\omega R C}
$$
In terms of dB's,

$$
  \text{dBV} = 20 \log \frac{ |V_{out}| }{|V_{in}|} \approx 20 \log \frac{1}{\omega R C} = -20 \log \omega - 20 \log RC
$$

If the frequency increases by a factor of 10, so does \$\omega\$ and thus the amplitude decreases by 20 dBV.

Frequencies below the cutoff, \$\omega < \frac{1}{RC}\$, \$1+\omega^2R^2C^2\$ is dominated by the 1, and so:

$$
\frac{ |V_{out}| }{|V_{in}|} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \omega^2R^2C^2}} 
\approx
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} = 1
$$
so the amplitude is attenuated very little.